# Is there a way to force multiply defined symbols using GCC/Clang on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, symbols

I am working with two separate libraries ([PLCIO](https://www.ctiplcio.com/) and [azure-iot-sdk-c](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c)) on a project. This project is being developed primarily on Windows using Visual Studio, but needs to run on Linux in production. I'm currently using a Ubuntu box to simulate production. When compiling the program in Visual Studio on Windows I get the linker errors [LNK2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(LNK2005)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019) and [LNK1169](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk1169?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(LNK1169)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019).  I solved this problem by using the [**/FORCE:MULTIPLE**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/force-force-file-output?view=vs-2019) linker option in Visual Studio. Our app compiles and runs as expected on Windows.

[image: Visual Studio Linker Errors Screenshot]

When I port the code and libraries over to my Linux test box, I am using cmake to build and link everything. The project builds and links properly, but when it runs I get an unexpected segmentation fault. I've narrowed it down to an interaction between the two libraries by creating stub programs using one library at a time and confirming that they work as expected. It's only when I put both libraries together that I run into problems. I think it is a fair assumption that the same multiply defined symbols error is causing this seg fault on Linux, it just isn't caught during compile for some reason.

I have tried a whole host of compile and linker flags (using both GCC and Clang) to build this project to try and fix this issue. I have tried `-fvisibility=hidden` `-shared` `-nostdlib`. I found `-symbolic` in the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html), but am getting a "option not recognized" error when I try to use it. I was originally statically linking to pre-built libraries, but have also tried both dynamically linking and also building the azure-iot-sdk myself with the rest of my code. I am getting the same result every time.

Essentially my question comes down to, is there any equivalent of **/FORCE:MULTIPLE** for a Linux tool chain (GCC, Clang, I don't care) that can fix this problem. Or, is there some alternative solution that I have somehow missed in my hours and hours of Googling and troubleshooting?

Comment: What symbols are exported in both libraries? Compile both libraries to a static (or shared) library and list the symbols and compare. Most probably that `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` picks one of two symbols - just `gcc` picks the wrong one, but both approaches are bad. Use `objcopy` to rename the offending symbol and develop against the renamed symbol. Alternatively, and much simpler, just develop two separate processes, one for each library, and do interprocess communication.

Comment: You should show the code. It is probably easier to fix the One Definition Rule (ODR) violations then it is to hack around them. Hacking around them will likely cause obscure errors that are hard to diagnose.

Comment: @jww I do not have access to the code as these are two pre-built libraries I am linking to. Based on the [errors shown in Visual Studio](https://i.gyazo.com/13e685d3c08b7bd6b24f12291c64b341.png) it looks like ```_get_time``` is the offending symbol, but I cannot edit the source code of these libraries, nor am I ever referencing this symbol directly in my own code.

Comment: Can you confirm that **both** libraries contain a function named `get_time()`? You don't need to call it in your code, it suffices if a function called from your code calls it. Let the linker create a cross reference to have some insight.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot confirm that both libraries contain a ```get_time()```. I did a grep on the source code from the azure-iot-sdk git repo and can find references to ```get_time()```, but not a definition. I do not have the source for the other library so I cannot check that. The only reason I think ```get_time()``` is the offending function is because of the Visual Studio error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I decided to move forward with running two separate processes with inter-process communication to solve this problem.**

While it may have been possible to use another solution like `objcopy`, since I don't know exactly what's going on in these libraries and don't have the time to familiarize myself with all of Microsoft's source code, it seems the path of least resistance is using two processes. Thanks everything for your help with this and hopefully this thread can help someone in the future.